# Angular2 Router's RouterLink unexpected behaviour

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I am seeing some unexpected behavior of `RouterLink` directive of Angular2.

My route is `/channel/:id`

```
<a [routerLink]=['/channel',{id:c.id}]>
```

Its output should be

```
<a href="/channel/122">
```

however it is parsed as

```
<a href="/channel;id=123">
```

And also how to link route like `/channel/:id/remove-user` ?

Comment: have you define you route like this `/channel/:id` ?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue porting from Angular 1 to Angular 2 RC.1 router. Try changing your links to:

```
<a [routerLink]=['/channel', c.id]>
<a [routerLink]=['/channel', c.id, 'remove-user']>
```

Seems like the new router in RC.1 doesn't use object parameters to fill in the :abc type parameters in the route. Instead object parameters are used only as query parameters. And the RC.1 router seems to use ;id=123;x=abc instead of ?id=123&x=abc. And I have not found a way to change that yet. But it should be possible to provide your own url serializer, so it might be added in later release.